# How to make a similar function as componentDidUpdate function in a functional component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to set an error message for a registration form but because I am using material UI, I had to use the functional component for my project. I was following a tutorial on youtube but the guy was using a class component. I managed to convert most of the codes to a functional component but I am lost at the componentDidUpdate function.

I also tried to use useEffect function but to no avail I couldn't display the alert/message error when somebody clicks the submit button if they did not enter any fields. I also got an error that the msg is not defined in the Alert component within the SignUp component eventhough it is already defined in the useState function.

```
{msg ? <Alert color="danger">{msg}</Alert> : null}
```

Below is the code for SignUp component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Logo from "./assets/images/logo_transparent.png";
import { Alert } from "reactstrap";


//redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
//proptypes
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { register } from "./actions/authActions";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
//styles- for brevity only
})); 

function SignUp(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [form, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    msg: null
  });

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate
  //By running an empty array [] as a second argument,
  //we’re letting React know that the useEffect function doesn’t
  //depend on any values from props or state.
  useEffect(() => {
    const { error } = props;
    if (error !== form.error) {
      //check for register error
      if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
        setValues({ msg: error.msg.msg });
      } else {
        setValues({ msg: null });
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const onChange = e => {
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      [e.target.email]: e.target.value,
      [e.target.password]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, password } = form;

    //create user object
    const newUser = {
      name,
      email,
      password
    };

    //attempt to register
    props.register(newUser);

    window.confirm("Registration details: " + name + " " + email);
    //window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/";
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />

      <div className={classes.paper}>
        {msg ? <Alert color="danger">{msg}</Alert> : null}
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="name"
                name="name"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="name"
                label="Full Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="cpassword"
                label="Confirm Password"
                type="password"
                id="cpassword"
                autoComplete="confirm-password"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} />
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>

          <Button
            href="http://localhost:3000/"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.home}
          >
            Home
          </Button>
          <br />
          <br />

          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="http://localhost:3000/signin" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

SignUp.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.error //getting from reducer
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { register } //from redux actions //mapdispatchtoprop
)(SignUp); //component
```

This is the original componentDidUpdate function

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const {error} = this.props;
  if(error !== prevProps.error){
    //check for register error
    if(error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL"){
      this.setState({msg:error.msg.msg});
    }else {
        setValues({ msg: null });
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should definitely be a class-based Component, no point in using a functional Component here IMHO.

Comment: Hi @TobiasTengler. May I ask why a Function Component (FC) would not work here? I'd like to know why (not trying to argue, just want to understand your thought process )

Comment: I never said that it wouldn't work, just that a class-based Component would make more sense for me personally. In general functional components should be *dumb* and only render things that are supplied to them via props. There are a bunch of handlers in there and OP wants to add even more complexity by introducing life-cycle hooks. I guess react encourages FC as of more recent updates, maybe I'm just to old fashioned in that regard, who knows, just personal preference.

Comment: I am sorry, I misread your previous message ... So how I understood is that, FC should be used as a "presentation" while CC (class components) be used as a "container/controller"?

Comment: @TobiasTengler I understand your opinion that using a class component is far better but I am still also trying to learn Hooks to make a functional component have states. Plus, as far as I know, material-ui does not support class component.

Comment: what led you to believe that material-ui doesn't support class-based Components? Of course it does! @SungM.Kim exactly.

Comment: Your `useEffect` call should run whenever `props.error` is updated, so you should have that value in the observables array in the function definition, i.e. `useEffect(() => { ... }, [props.error])`. As it is, with an empty array, useEffect will fire only once, after the initial render.

Comment: @Jaxx I still get the 'msg' is not defined error eventhough it's already been defined before.

Comment: @TobiasTengler It might be possible but the makeStyles component in Material UI from the documentation are mostly function-based. Anyways, do you have any insights for the question above?

Comment: `makeStyles` is just a function and if you export your Component with the `withStyles` HOC it should work just fine.

Comment: @TobiasTengler I was aware of MUI supporting CCs but I found FC as recommended way as Dan tweeted that [FB uses hooks for new code](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1135407371566624769).

Answer (score 3):

When you think of `useEffect` as a function that runs when a "side effect" (changing state) as `componentDidUpdate` is used, you need to watch out for changes in both `error` and `msg` states.

Instead of

```
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate
  //By running an empty array [] as a second argument,
  //we’re letting React know that the useEffect function doesn’t
  //depend on any values from props or state.
  useEffect(() => {
    const { error } = props;
    if (error !== form.error) {
      //check for register error
      if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
        setValues({ msg: error.msg});
      } else {
        setValues({ msg: null });
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

You need to do

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { error } = props;
    if (error !== form.error) {
      //check for register error
      if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
-        setValues(({ msg: error.msg});
+       setValues({ ...form, msg: error.msg});
      } else {
-       setValues({ msg: null });
+       setValues({ ...form, msg: null });
      }
    }
  }, [error, form.msg]);
```

The reason I am spreading `...form` like `setValues({ ...form, msg: error.msg.msg })` is because an updator function (2nd argument) returned by `React.useState` does not update other properties in the state.

So `setValues({ msg: null });` would turn `form` from

```
{
  name: 'previous name',
  password: 'previous password',
  email: 'previous email',
  msg: 'previous message...'
}
```

into `{msg: null}` removing `name, email, password` properties.

As the behavior between `React.useState`'s updator ("aliased" as `setState` in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) and `setState` is different someone ended up creating [use-legay-state NPM package](https://twitter.com/suchipi/status/1059334348552364032), which you probably shouldn't be using unless absolutely necessary.

### Side note

Unrelated to your question, you'd also want to either
1. separate `name/email/password/msg` into separate states
2. "or" use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook.

#### Implementation change for case 1

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
```

Should you want to keep using an object `form`, you might want to follow a convention of naming by changing `setValues` to `setForm` or `const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({...})`.

And you can update each field like,

```
<TextField
  autoComplete="name"
  name="name"
  variant="outlined"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="name"
  label="Full Name"
  autoFocus
  value={name}
  onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

*You can use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for `onChange` like `onChange={useCallback(e => setName(e.target.value), [name])}` here but not necessary unless you have a performance issue.  Start simple initially*

And also it'd make your `useEffect` to depend on `msg` only.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { error } = props;
    if (error !== form.error) {
      //check for register error
      if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
       setMessage(error.msg);
      } else {
       setMessage(null);
      }
    }
  }, [error, message]);
```

Here I changed `setValues` to `setMessage` and dependency array from `[error, form]` to `[error, message]`.

#### Implementation change for case 2

If you want to use `useReducer`, it seems like more work as you are changing indivisual form field, which are changed separately. `useReducer` works better when you update a related set of states that should change together. But in your case, each state (`password/name` etc) change independently as user input so it'd be easier to get started with case #1 above.

Comment: Thank you. This is certainly a big help and detailed explanation. I will try case #1 and will get back to you if I have any question regarding hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a minimal example with form field validation and functional components.
Note, that you can write any component as function **and** as class. I personally prefer functions, because they are often more concise.

Run the example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-antonelli-noovi?fontsize=14

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
     {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      <form>
        <input
          type="email"
          onInvalid={() => setError("That is not an email.")}
          required
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` with empty dependencies array will **not** act like `componentDidUpdate`, it will **only** run when the component first mounts and will not when the component `re-renders`

To mimic `componentDidUpdate` provide the `error` as a dependency.

```
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
    setErrorMsg(props.error.msg.msg);
  }
}, [props.error])

return (
  <div className="App">
  {errorMsg && <span>{errorMsg}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

I would also suggest every time you submit the form to dispatch an action and reset the error msg to a falsy value `''` in the store

This way every time you submit you won't see the last `error` and won't need to compare `errors`.

Comment: Thanks for the code above. I managed to display the message using some of the code above.